# Open one VC from another without pushing them to Navigation stack (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have two VC (MapController and ObjectListController).
I put them to navigation controller (I need navigation bar with button to switch between them, looks as on picture).

[image]

But when I click to NavButton I switched to ObjectList but appears BackButton item that I don't need. ObjectListController have the same button to switch to MapController.

**How can do such behavior between two VC by right way: Switching from one to another without pushing them to Navigation stack ?**

Now buttons and VCs connected using custom segue without any code.

PS: If I remove navigation controller wrapper, I don't see navigation bar to put buttons for switching.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the navigation controller to push/pop as normal, simply hide the back button that is provided by default:

To do this you set the property [`hidesBackButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/hidesBackButton) in ObjectListController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    // ...
}
```

Comment: is it really correct way ? suppose with hiding back button VCs will pushed to stack and memory will utilize again and again

Comment: This is *a* way of doing it, however you are correct, it will keep the view controller in memory. However if you push to `ObjectListController`, then **pop** back to `MapController` you will only, at most, have 2 view controllers in memory at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To choose a better way, you need to know what ObjectListController will do. For a simple display view controller, you can push/present to it and customize your own navigation bar. The back button is actually a `UIBarButtonItem` that can be create and customize. Highly recommend this. By the way you can even hide the system navigation bar and simulate it using a UIView..

If these two controllers have complex interactions of each other, you may try tab bar controller and just hide the tab bar. Let the button selector method do a toggle tab action.

If the ObjectListController is simple enough, you can even just use a `UIView?` as attribute of your current view controller to replace your ObjectListController.